# Proving Coprime nature of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to prove that Fibonacci numbers $F_i, F_{i+3}$ can be either coprime, where $i$ and $i+3$ are not both even, or they can have a greatest common divisor of $2$, when $i$ and $i+3$ are even.

I've tried using the formula that $gcd(F_m, F_n) = F_{gcd(m,n)}$, but I've not been able to come up with a full proof that ensures that the greatest common factor of Fibonacci numbers 3 terms apart have a maximum greatest common divisor of 2.

Is there any way to prove this maximum of 2, or that $F_i, F_{i+3}$ are coprime, except for when $i$ and $i+3$ are even?

Comment: $i$ and $i+3$ cannot both be even.  Did you mean both are multiples of $3$?  (Depends on the indexing of $F_n$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n+3} \\ F_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1\\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n} \\ F_{n-3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix has determinant $-1$ and so has an integer inverse. Therefore, $\gcd(F_{n+3},F_n)=\gcd(F_{n},F_{n-3})$.

Thus it suffices to compute $\gcd(F_{3},F_{0})=2$, $\gcd(F_{4},F_{1})=1$, $\gcd(F_{5},F_{2})=1$.

Comment: Thank you! This was a really nice way of proving it!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $d \mid i$ and $d \mid (i+3),$ then $d \mid 3.$ What does that tell you about $\gcd(i, i+3)$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\gcd(i,i+3) \in \{1,3\}$ because $d \mid i$ and $d \mid i+3$, then $d \mid (i+3)-i=3$. Thus
$$\gcd(F_i, F_{i+3})=F_1 \text{ or } F_3=1 \text{ or } 2.$$
You can also note that $\gcd(i,i+3)=3$ if and only $3 \mid i$.